# How to map URL with directory structure for PHP project

Tags: php, url, directory-structure, url-mapping

I want to create a folder structure for my PHP project like in the image.

[image]

`Public` folder has the **UI code** files and `src` folder has the **back-end code** files. But the problem is when I want to visit the page from browser, I have to put the folder name in the URL.

Like if I want to go to `home.php` I'll have to type `http://localhost/public/home.php`. So I want to remove the `/public` from my url so it should look like `http://localhost/home.php`

So is there a way where I can map the file's path to URL and I can visit that URL from browser?

Comment: I am using Apache as a server.

Comment: Look up ___Virtual Host___ in the Apache manual

Comment: Whoever has marked this question as already asked, please remove it. I am not looking for that solution. It's not related.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a htaccess if you're using apache to make this work.

the code would be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/$1.php
```

Then the url for your home.php would be domain.tld/home

Explanation:
`Options +FollowSymLinks`
Options FollowSymLinks enables you to have a symlink in your webroot pointing to some other file/dir. With this disabled, Apache will refuse to follow such symlink

`RewriteEngine on`
Turns on the RewriteEngine :) so you are able to use rewrite conditions and rules etc.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
Like an if that checks if the url (i.E. domain.tld/home) is NOT a directory
because then we want to just access the directory and its index.html or .php ...

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /public/$1.php`
This is the Rule for what to rewrite.

`^` This means that we are rewriting withing this folder (the .htaccess should be in the root directory where the public folder is too)

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` This checks wether the part of the url (domain.tld/home) the part here would be home contains nothing else than letters a-z A-Z and numbers 0-9 the `+` means that the url can have more than one char, the `$` signals the end of the "url checker"

`/public/$1.php` This is the file the url should link too.
Because we are in the root folder, we need to get to /public and because the url is domain.tld/home `$1` is home so it opens /public/home.php but the url stays domain.tld/home

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you please explain the code?